# SEO for infinite scroll homepage with sorting options and content previews

Tags: seo

I have a site which shows an infinite feed of post previews (with the option to read full text using javascript). The page allows users to click through to the full-text of any post, and change the order in which posts are sorted. There are a few SEO considerations I have questions about. See the attached image for HTML architectural reference.

1. The "trending" sort option excludes posts with fewer than 140 characters, meaning not ALL content is guaranteed to appear on the homepage (which uses "trending" as it's default sorting option). However, I want the homepage to be the highest priority page, so adding rel=canonical to from "trending" to "newest" isn't too appealing. What's the best way to deal with this?
2. Javascript loading of full-text without changing pages just uses a hidden  element to store the text until the user requests it by clicking "continue reading." Does this present a potential duplicate content issue?
3. Individual post pages contain the full-text of content that can be shown on the homepage from time to time. Does this present yet another duplicate content issue?
4. Infinite scrolling uses a "startIndex" parameter for pagination to allow for load more functionality. As the content fluctuates from day to day, Google's indexed content for loadmore URLs becomes outdated. Is there anything I can/should do to accommodate?

[image: HTML Homepage Architecture]

Comment: I am sorry, but single page sites do not rank well. You are defeating the single most important factor that you have to influence placement in the SERPs- pages of content.